# How to send static images from an iOS app to a Chromecast?

Tags: ios, chromecast

I am trying to send still images from iOS app to chromecast and show them on tv but always failed. I am using the latest chromecast Ultra(hardware) and chromecast ios sdk 3.3.0 with sample code [CastVideos-ios](https://github.com/googlecast/CastVideos-ios) as example, the receiver side is the default receiver.

Part of the code:

```
 mediaInformation =
[[GCKMediaInformation alloc] initWithContentID:
 @"https://images3.alphacoders.com/276/276565.jpg"
                                    streamType:GCKMediaStreamTypeNone
                                   contentType:@"image/jpg"
                                      metadata:metadata
                                streamDuration:0
                                    customData:nil];
    GCKCastSession *castSession =
    [GCKCastContext sharedInstance].sessionManager.currentCastSession;
    if (castSession) {
        [castSession.remoteMediaClient loadMedia:mediaInformation];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"no castSession!");
    }
```

Can anyone give me a hint? Thanks a lot.

BTW: Using the sample code [CastHelloVideo-ios](https://github.com/googlecast/CastHelloVideo-ios) I could cast a still image successfully. But the api in this sample seems deprecated.

Comment: "always fails" is too vague t get any feedback., What failure do you get? What does the cast device show? Also, if you use a Styled receiver, you can see the log on the receiver side as well.

Comment: Thanks to Ali Naddaf very much. I tried styled receiver and every things works now.

Comment: I used styled receiver with default styles. iOS app code keep unchanged. and it works. so I guess the default receiver has some difference in processing still image.

Comment: @TechGitKool, I need to share iOS gallery image over Google Chrome cast. How can I achieve that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem. I just changed the Receiver Application ID to default (kGCKDefaultMediaReceiverApplicationID or kGCKMediaDefaultReceiverApplicationID) then it worked.
https://developers.google.com/cast/v2/receiver_apps#default